# Given text in a #define, can it somehow be passed to a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

Say I have a macro, FOO(name), and some template class Bar<> that takes one parameter (what type of parameter is the question). Everytime I call FOO with a different name, I want to get a different instantiation of Bar. The Bar<> template doesn't actually need to be able to get at the name internally, I just need to be sure that different names create different instances of Bar<> and that using the same name (even in different translation units) always gets at the same instance of Bar<>. So here's a rough first attempt:

```
template<const char* x>
class Bar
{
//... stuff
};

#define FOO(name) Bar<#name>
```

This would work, except that char literals can't be passed as template parameters because they don't have external linkage. If there was someway in the preprocessor to get a consistent hash of 'name' to say, an int (which can then be passed to the template) that would work, but I don't see any way to do that.

Ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: A ludicrous abuse of the C++ language ;)

This is going to be part of an open source library that will be released soon, I'll comment back here once it is so you can see ;)

Comment: This was used in the implementation of TOAST_STATIC_INIT_PROTECTED for the open source Toast library in version 1.2. Link to documentation:

http://toast.sourceforge.net/group__miscgroup.html#gdb5e38486385cb4eb10848f0d573fe24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where you intend to use this macro (namespace or class scope would work), you could create a tag type and use that:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar
{
//... stuff
};

#define FOO(name) struct some_dummy_tag_for_##name {}; Bar<some_dummy_tag_for_##name>
```

If this doesn't work, maybe you can "declare" those names before-hand:

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(name) struct some_dummy_tag_for_##name {}
#define FOO(name) Bar<some_dummy_tag_for_##name>

// something.h
DECLARE_FOO(foobar);

// something.cpp
FOO(foobar);
```

Comment: surely you mean `template<typename T>`?

Comment: @bdonlan: Um, yeah, I just copied the code without really thinking. Sorry. Will fix.

Comment: You sir, are a genius :) This incidentally solves like 3 other issues my old method had.

Comment: Also at the time of this posting our scores match exactly, kind of cool coincidence.